# FileType multiple for collection field

Tags: forms, symfony, file-upload, collections, entity

I am trying to create a Symfony form for creating and editing an entity called 'Movie', that is uploading an image files path to the database and the files to the server folder. I want the uploading of these files to be multiple and able for drag and drop with preview of the image and the possibility for deleting a single image before submitting the form. This entity is having a collection field named 'images'(entity 'Image' with relation - One movie Many images).

I could do the creating of this entity with FileType::class that is multiple(with the preview, drag, drop), but the problem comes when I will want to edit this 'movie', I don't see how I will be able to edit the entity with the same functionality when the field is collection and I am using FileType::class. 
My question is am I in the right way doing this, or there is some better option, if yes if I could use some help will be awesome.

This is my design at the moment:
[image: File Input Div]

[image]

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

With files or images there is a difference between new files and already uploaded files and that is that new files are still on the client and when your previously uploaded files would like to edit they are already on the server.

so to edit your movie you could simply render each image with a foreach in twig with an trash icon and with some javascript and ajax you could remove the image from the movie entity and destroy the image file too. under the images you can show your drag n drop box again so that images could be added to the movie entity.

Comment: Yeah this is what I was thinking as well, but I wanted the images that are still on the client and on the server to be in the same div and probably to reuse the same form for new and edit. Maybe I could for each them inside as well hmm..